# Devise encryption for mobile application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, encryption, devise

I'm building a RESTfull API for my mobile applications. I have a problem concerning the authentication. I do not want to send the password as readable so I'd like to directly encrypt it before sending it on the network. The problem is that I do not find how to encrypt the password to make him match with password generated by devise.

Comment: Use SSL/TLS. There is not really another way except when you have some trusted value on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to encrypt passwords on mobile phone.

If you want to compare hashes on server - anyone who sniffs you traffic would get password hash and reuse it.

If someone will reverse-engineer your app - he will get algorithm for building such hashed.

Just use SSL/TLS as Artjom B. said, or look into using OAuth for authenticating mobile apps.

Comment: I do not want to decrypt passwords on the mobile phone but encrypt the input from user to send it to the API, for authentication.

Comment: sorry, it was typo in my answer. of course I meant 'encrypt'